# Using jQuery how do I run a function after click event

Tags: jquery, click

I wrote a basic function to show some more elements on a page.  I have 8 total items and I show 3 at a time.  If the user click "show" once, they get 3 more items.  If they click it again, they get the last 2.  But then I want to disable the "More" button.

```
function showMoreRelated(count){
    var hiddenEls = $('#ps-item-related-contents .related-contents > div.row:hidden');
    var countArray=[];i=0;while(countArray.push(i++)<count);

    if (hiddenEls.length>0)
        {
            hiddenEls.each(function(i){ 
                if($.inArray(i, countArray) > -1)
                {
                    $(this).show();
                }
            });
            // CHECK NUMBER OF hiddenEls, disable button if # is 0
        } 
}

$('.related-items-more a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    showMoreRelated(3);
});
```

I have a comment where I think I need to run this but I have no idea what to run to recheck hiddenEls.  I do know how to disable the button.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your HTML is such that `$('#ps-item-related-contents .related-contents > div.row:hidden')` really is the most efficient way to locate your hidden elements, then you probably just need:

```
function showMoreRelated(count){
    var hiddenEls = $('#ps-item-related-contents .related-contents > div.row:hidden');

    if (hiddenEls.length <= count) {
        $('.related-items-more a').off('click');  //disables button
        $('.related-items-more a').on('click',function(){return false;});  // stops link
    }

    while (count--) {
        if (hiddenEls[count]) {
            // needs to be wrapped inside an if because there could be less
            // hidden elements than the value of count

            hiddenEls.eq(count).show()   // shows divs
        } 
    }

}

$('.related-items-more a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    showMoreRelated(3);
});
```

Since hiddenEls is a new variable each time, you don't need to bother with `countArray`. Those elements that are already shown will automatically be removed from it.

Comment: what would a more efficient way of finding all hidden divs? This essentially does what I want it too, but it doesn't automate the disabling of the href.  In my example with 8, we wind up with 2,  the user clicks again, and it should show the 2 and disable.hide the button without needing another click.

Comment: ok, there's a couple of ways to stop the link from working. I added one to the code in the answer. The selector you use to find the hidden elements seems very specific, which can be inefficient. You basically want the selector to be as simple as possible, but whilst still being specific enough to target the right elements. Without seeing your HTML, I couldn't say what that would be. Maybe just `$('#ps-item-related-contents div.row:hidden')`?

Comment: also, is there any reason why you're using an anchor tag with a href attribute? judging from this, it's default behaviour will always be stopped. It is just as a non-javascript fallback?

Comment: IF I understand you right, maybe using a span tag as the "button" would be better, and less code.  There is no fallback behavior. The main remaining issue for me is simply how to auto hide the button after the last items are shown... thanks

Comment: yeah, i'm just saying, you don't need to use an anchor tag unless you're using the underlying properties of an anchor tag for something.

Answer (score 0):

```
var normalShow = 3;
var showMore = 2;
var showing = 0;

function showRelated(){
    var hiddenEls = $('#ps-item-related-contents .related-contents > div.row:hidden');
    if (showing === 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < normalShow; i++) {
            hiddenEls[i].show();
        }
        showing = normalShow;

    } else if (showing === normalShow) {
        for (var i = 0; i < showMore; i++) {
            hiddenEls[i].show();
        }
        showing += normalShow;

    } else {
        $('.related-items-more a').prop('enabled', false);
    }
}

$('.related-items-more a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    showRelated();
});
```

Comment: I assume your thought here is that all the top vars would be set by some kind of calc.  These are dynamic numbers for me.  it might be 16 total, or 100 total...